# Realtime SQL Server data in Blazor server app WITHOUT sqltabledependency

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a Blazor server app that will live stream some data from SQL Server.

The problem I'm facing is the SQL Server I'm watching is a reporting server that only has views to a linked server, thus `SqlTableDependency` isn't an option.

How can I get around this?

Comment: You don't. If you only have views, your options are 1) poll continuously for changes or 2) get the people responsible for changing the data to give you an event of some sort (API call, service broker message, what have you) when they change the data. Things like CDC can help here, or roll-your-own triggers, but the key is that only the data owners are positioned to do this.

Comment: Fair enough. Sqltabledependency doesn't work on a linked sever by chance?

Comment: You can add a Signalr as aHostedservice into Blazor Server App and which will send a signal to the client page for refresh every 5 seconds.

Comment: Under the covers the table dependency just sets up a query notification with a service broker queue. Query notifications are tightly integrated with the engine and come with a bunch of restrictions to ensure the engine doesn't have to work too hard to detect changes. Linked servers are right out.